# Ffmpeg change bitrate of .mp2 file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, bitrate

How can I change the bitrate of an .mp2 file usin ffmpeg.

So far I tried following:

```
ffmpeg -i myAudio.mp2 -minrate 160k -maxrate 160k -bufsize 160k myAudioNew.mp2
```

It creates me an Audio but if I go into the file details (Windows) the bitrate is different.

Comment: Have you tried setting the bitrate `-b:a 160k`?

Comment: @Mulvya That worked, would you like to answer so I can thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bitrate was expressly set. Use

```
ffmpeg -i myAudio.mp2 -b:a 160k -minrate 160k -maxrate 160k -bufsize 160k myAudioNew.mp2
```